# Why invoking the event cancels the task?

Tags: c#, events, task

I have a Task that checks the time of a device per second:

```
public void checkTimeStart()
{
  CancellationTokenSource cTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  CancellationToken ct = cTokenSource.Token;
  Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
      ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
         {
           await Task.Delay(1000);
           string time = getTime();
           TimeUpdateEvent.Invoke(this, new TimeUpdateEventArgs(time));
          }
     }, cTokenSource.Token);
}
```

This works perfect if I remove the `TimeUpdateEvent.Invoke(this, new TimeUpdateEventArgs(time));`. But when I try to invoke the event the task stops completely and it never enters the while loop! I need this event to update time text box whenever I recieve the new time from the device.

---

I know its possible to update ui directly from anonymous task but this method is implemented in a portable class library. I need it to be platform independent. So every user could update its own ui when they receive TimeUpdateEvent. *TimeUpdateEvent is a simple custom event.*

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: Please be more specific than "stops completely". Are you saying the task simply exits? Or that it gets blocked waiting at some statement? If it never even enters the while loop, how could it make any difference whether the call to the delegate's `Invoke()` method is there or not? It seems more likely to me that the event handler _does_ get called, but there is something in it that results in a deadlock. But lacking [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to say what's wrong.

Comment: Are you sure `TimeUpdateEvent` is NOT `null`?One possibility could be `TimeUpdateEvent` is throwing an exception. Please check output window while debuging the code for any `exception`.

Comment: It works only for the first time. It enters the while. gets the time and invokes the event. but exits the loop and task ended. (No block it simply exits) When I remove the `invoke`. It repeats the loop until I cancel it using `cTokenSource.Cancel()`

Comment: Set the debugger to CLR exceptions and observe if an exception is thrown inside the `Task`. Don't forget the tasks encapsulate exceptions, and in this case you're not using `.Result`, `.Wait` or `await`, which will swallow the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if there is any subscription to the event "TimeUpdateEvent" before calling the "checkTimeStart()" method. I think you didn't make any subscription, so on invoking that event system halts. If you will put the invocation part of the code in try catch block:

```
try
{
    TimeUpdateEvent.Invoke(this, new TimeUpdateEventArgs(time));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

you will get a NullReferenceException ....
So please check the subscription to that event.

Wish you all the best !

Comment: Do not forget to set a breackpoint on throw; line in catch block

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem was actually out of Task. But it didn't handle the exception and it exit from Task, throwing nothing.